# Trace space of $H^2(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is Lipschitz

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $\mathscr{T}:H^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\partial \Omega)$ be the trace operator defined in the usual way.  Is there a characterization of its image?  It is clearly a subspace of  $H^1(\partial\Omega)$; is it necessarily a closed subspace?

Comment: In this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/275418/14551 the book is cited where traces of functions from Sobolev spaces on a  Lipschitz boundary are characterized.

Answer (score 2):

From *Elliptic problems in nonsmooth domains* by P. Grisvard:

> **Theorem 1.5.1.3.** Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with a Lipschitz boundary $\Gamma$. Then the mapping $u\to \gamma u$ which is defined for $u\in C^{0,1}(\overline{\Omega})$, has a unique continuous extension as an operator from $W^1_p(\Omega)$ onto $W^{1-\frac{1}{p}}_p(\Gamma)$. This operator has a right continuous inverse independent of $p$.

Answer (score 1):

For $1<p<\infty$, the image of the trace operator on $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ is $W^{m-\frac{1}{p},p}(\partial\Omega)$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Traces

As a reference they give

> Adams, Robert A.; Fournier, John (2003) [1975]. Sobolev Spaces. Pure and Applied Mathematics. 140 (2nd ed.). Boston, MA: Academic Press. ISBN 978-0-12-044143-3..

Comment: Johannes: this is the case when the boundary is sufficiently smooth. But what is H^{3/2} when it is Lipschitz?

Comment: As user113499 says, I don't believe the reference you cite gives an answer.  Standard definitions of the space $H^{3/2}\left(\partial\Omega\right)$ generally require that the domain have a boundary which is $C^{1,1}$ not $C^{0,1}$.  Or perhaps I am missing something in the definitions in Adams and Fournier?